# Are these temperatures okay?

Tags: cpu, temperature, cooling

These are my computer specs: (collected with Everest):

```
Field                        Value
CPU Properties  
CPU Type                     Intel Pentium 4, 2800 MHz (21 x 133)
CPU Alias                    Northwood
CPU Stepping                 D1
Instruction Set              x86, MMX, SSE, SSE2
Original Clock               2800 MHz
Min / Max CPU Multiplier     21x / 21x
Engineering Sample           No
L1 Trace Cache               12K Instructions
L1 Data Cache                8 KB
L2 Cache                     512 KB  (On-Die, ECC, ATC, Full-Speed)

CPU Physical Info   
Package Type                 478 Pin uPGA
Package Size                 3.50 cm x 3.50 cm
Transistors                  55 million
Process Technology           6M, 0.13 um, CMOS, Cu, Low-K
Die Size                     131 mm2
Core Voltage                 1.475 - 1.55 V
I/O Voltage                  1.475 - 1.55 V
Typical Power                38.7 - 89.0 W  (depending on clock speed)
Maximum Power                49 - 109 W  (depending on clock speed)

CPU Manufacturer    
Company Name                 Intel Corporation
Product Information          http://www.intel.com/products/processor


Sensor Type                 Analog Devices ADM1027  (SMBus 2Eh)
Motherboard Name            HP d530 
Motherboard                 48 °C  (118 °F)
CPU                         70 °C  (158 °F)
SAMSUNG SV4002H             31 °C  (88 °F)
WDC WD1600JB-00GVA0         43 °C  (109 °F)
```

I think my CPU is overheating but SpeedFan show these values:

```
CPU: 45C
Local: 46C
Remote2: 53C
```

I don't believe the Everest temperatures because nothing lags and the system runs stable. What should I believe in? Is my PC ok? What can I do to cool down the PC?

**UPDATE**
Thanks for all answers! I have changed "Fan Idle Mode" in BIOS and now "EVEREST" shows 55C - 65C, "Speed Fan" shows 40C. But no effect to performance.

**UPDATE**
"HWMonitor PRO" shows about from 34.0C to 46.0C core temp.

Comment: Download [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) or [CoreTemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) and report what you get for temperature readings using *those* programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar Intel processors (Intel® Pentium 4 Northwood Processor 2.80 GHz, 512K Cache) with 533 and 800 Mhz FSB has the following specifications regarding temperature:

http://ark.intel.com/compare/27447,27495

```
- 533 MHz FSB, TCASE: 70°C
 -800 MHz FSB, TCASE: 75°C
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.intel.com/design/pentium4/datashts/298643.htm) and [here](http://download.intel.com/design/Pentium4/datashts/29864312.pdf) (pdf).

> **Tc (Tcase - Intel labs):** Temperature measured at the geometric center
>   of the surface of the CPU. The only way to measure it is to crave a
>   hairline groove in the CPU and apply/solder a hair-sized thermostat
>   probe into the CPU's IHS. This is the way Intel measured the
>   temperature to give the Thermal Specification of each CPU.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question directly, but I have a computer of the same generation (Pentium 4 Northwood 2 GHz @100 MHz FSB, overclocked to 2.66 GHz @ 133 MHz FSB). Mainboard is unknown, but the chipset seems to be SiS 645DX. Everest couldn't get thermal reading off the sensor, but SpeedFan reported my CPU temperature to be 40 C. Note that ambient temperature in this room is around 23-25 C.

Comment: Look at the graphs to see if the values change, particularly if you put a load on the CPU or if you point a fan at the system. If they don’t change, then the values are bad and you may want to try changing some of the options to see if SpeedFan can pick up the right one.

Comment: @Synetech: Yup, the temp fluctuates under load, going as high as 48 C. Idle temperature from cold boot is around 39-40 C.

Comment: If 48 is the max you get, then that’s pretty good. Of course the ambient temperature plays a big part. In the summer, my room is already burning hot as it is, so my system spikes to 60°C pretty easily, so I avoid turning the computer on during heat waves like last week.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering about safe temperatures, check [this Intel page](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/pentium4/sb/CS-030107.htm). You can also read a [lengthy technical document](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/pentium4/sb/cs-007999.htm) on the subject or just [skip to the table](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/pentium4/sb/cs-007999.htm#Thermal) which indicates that your CPU is rated for a maximum of 75°C.

Also, you can find [support for your CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/581) or just skip to your [specific one](http://ark.intel.com/products/27495/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-supporting-HT-Technology-2_80-GHz-512K-Cache-800-MHz-FSB), which also says 75°C.

---

As for the inconsistent readings, try changing the method/sensor/chip that is used. In SpeedFan, you can do this in the Options tab of the Configure dialog. Try disabling `ISA Bus` and/or `SMBus`, also try running it with the `/NOACPISCAN` switch to disable ACPI. (You’re not using a DELL laptop are you? If so, SpeedFan has a specific option for that.) Also, try toggling the *debug* option.

Next, look at the Graphs tab and select the temps. See if the values go up and down. Try putting a load on the CPU by doing something processor intensive (eg watching a video on the Internet). Do any of the values in the graph go up? Try pointing a fan at your computer and see if any go down.

The line that fluctuates the most will be your CPU temperature, while the more stable one will be the system/mobo temp (the temps of the hard-drive(s) will also be pretty stable, but the motherboard will usually be lower and you can check it anyway by doing something like copying a large file since it will tax the drive, but not the CPU/mobo). You may also have a temperature that is really bizarre (eg -50°C), and you can just ignore that—and toggle it in the Configure dialog to not even be displayed. (I still have no idea what the heck that one is.)

Finally, look at SpeedFan’s log (in the text-field in the top-left corner, beside the buttons and above the CPU meters/temperatures). It will tell you what sensors it found and of any errors.

Oh and, check the Info tab. You can submit a report to Alfredo, who is usually pretty good at support. Also try the *Get Config* button ([you’ll need to register](http://www.almico.com/sfhandleconfig.php)). Your motherboard (not specified) may need specific settings (ie for the Clock tab), and someone else may have already made them available.

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry, even my MacBook Pro's CPU reaches high temperatures sometimes.
Just make sure your fan is working properly and you should be good.

How old is this computer? If it's a very old one, it might just be that if it's new you most likely don't need to worry about it. Is this a new occurrence or did you just never check before?

As soon as you see any performance issues, you should look at it in more detail, for example because of too much CPU / Memory Usage .. or whatever to identify the problem. But if it's just like that while using it normally, it's probably just the way the computer was meant to run.

Comment: My computer isn't OLD, i have created it from friends components.

Comment: alright then it should not be a problem, dont worry its probaly normal